# Which better welding inverter topology

Tags: inverter, topology

I have build a welding inverter using two switch forward (reference based http://danyk.cz). But I used Irgpc40u igbt(single each side) and sg3525 pwm. I test it at 900watt power line, 1.6mm electrode. Circuit breaker tripped when I increased output current. As result, metal object not cooked well.
Is 900 watt power line enough for welding?
And I also want to build one more, cz I still have many components at home. But I still doubt about better topology used. Which the better about 4 igbt for full bridge (with single igbt each side), compared with two switch forward (with double/paralelled igbt each side)?

Comment: *Is 900 watt power line enough for welding?* Not if you're welding iron girders together or are employed welding the infrastructure of large ships. You should post your schematic and ask a question that can have a fairly direct answer (unlike the 900 watt question).

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not ask about circuit or schematic. Cz circuit is relative same.
 And how about my last question?
 I need help. 
 Sorry for my bad English.